# How can I make a server push

Tags: java, server, long-polling

I developed my own client and server in java und I implemented a long-polling communication. So my client will always ask for new operations to be executed. If  a server has a new operation, then he will send it to the client. The whole communication is based on java-sockets. Now I am thinking to renounce on long-polling-communication and implement a server-push. In this case the client will not ask my server anymore. He will just wait for notifications. If my server has a new operation to be executed, then he will make a server-push.  My Goal is to save time on the client-side. So he will not send any request anymore

Question1: is it possible to implement a server-push on my model **based on sockets in Java** ?

Question2: if yes,how can I implement a server-push?

Comment: The server will send messages to the client. What stops you from doing just that ?

Comment: I thought, that the client must subscribe to something called channel.  At that time he can become notifications from the server. I really do not have any idea about it

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of Publish/Subscribe platform? Are you want to use plain sockets? Asking you because you mentioned `channel` in your comment.

Comment: What you are asking for is just a sophisticated version of what you have. Even in the push technology, there is a live connection between server and client. The client subscription is just a way of waiting for message from specific category.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a implementation of JMS

Comment: @Daniel: no,I do need an implementation of JMS. If I can do this called server-push based on sockets, then it is ok, since my goal is to save   the client from making requests.

Comment: @all: a paragraph in wikipidea confused me. That´s why I have posted this question. Here is the paragraph from wikipidea: Push services are often based on information preferences expressed in advance. This is called a publish/subscribe model. A client "subscribes" to various information "channels" provided by a server; whenever new content is available on one of those channels, the server pushes that information out to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side:

```
...    
DataOutputStream toClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
outToClient.writeBytes("event_xyz");
...
```

On client side you should listen for events

Comment: So is it called a server-push?

Comment: Wikipidea: Push services are often based on information preferences expressed in advance. This is called a publish/subscribe model. A client "subscribes" to various information "channels" provided by a server; whenever new content is available on one of those channels, the server pushes that information out to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question in the right way, you just have to wait for incoming data on the client. For example with a DataInputStream.readUTF(); this method waits until the ServerSocket pushes some data through the stream with the method DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String s) .

Comment: yes.If the client does not ask me any more and I make a post from the server to client. Is it then a push-server?

Comment: Wikipidea: Push services are often based on information preferences expressed in advance. This is called a publish/subscribe model. A client "subscribes" to various information "channels" provided by a server; whenever new content is available on one of those channels, the server pushes that information out to the client.

Comment: I think that's a "yes" ;D